# jquery remote ajax request is not returning any results

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am trying to make a request to this file : `http://traitdesign.com/work/tattva/get.php`
this is the code I have so far:

```
function getRemote() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://traitdesign.com/work/tattva/get.php',
        async: false,
    }).responseText;
}
getRemote();
```

well the issue is response headers is empty it doesnt return any results. any help would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: If that domain is different than the one the request is made from it will not work due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wiipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: That domain doesn't seem to be CORS enabled so you it will fail the same origin check.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `JSONP`

```
function getRemote() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://traitdesign.com/work/tattva/get.php',
        async: false,
        dataType: "jsonp",
    });
}
getRemote();
```

> "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra
>   "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables
>   caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the
>   URL unless the cache option is set to true.

Comment: Note that this will not work if that site does not support JSONP. But this is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is 'Same Origin Policy'. but you can escape from it. but some security issues will remain.
Please check this. http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Include this line into your get.php file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best in your case would be to write simple ajax action on your server like:

```
print(file_get_contents('http://traitdesign.com/work/tattva/get.php');
```

And make ajax call to your new action. It will got through your server so additional server work will be done but you then don't need to care about security policy.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONP with callback. Also return the value once the call is done.

```
function getRemote() {
  var jqXHR = $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "jsonp", 
     url: 'http://traitdesign.com/work/tattva/get.php',
     async: false,
     crossDomain: true
  });

  return jqXHR.responseText;
}

getRemote();
```